# Bootstrap div alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Unable to align container div which contains an image, immediately after the header tag end.

Here is the Jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu11/hef6rp23/

```
<div id="Intro">
<p style="margin-left:114px; padding:5px;">Welcome to our new and Mana Aravathi.</p>
</div>
<!------------------------------------------->
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="active">Know Aravathi</a>
        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Food and dining <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Local Dishes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Food Festivals</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dining Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Business</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Hotels</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Festival and events
</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want this container div to start after the header tag ends

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/11.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a reason for using the `.container` class, so what about adding a `.main` class that provides the nessecary padding from the top :

```css
.main {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```
<div class="container main">
    <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/11.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/58g39xs5/**

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the container class, it aligns properly.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hef6rp23/1/).

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.jssor.com/img/landscape/11.jpg" />
</div>
```

EDIT: if you want to move the image down then give it a new class ("main") and use the "margin-top" property in CSS like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hef6rp23/17/).

```
.main {margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: The image is starting from top..
I want the image to start after the nav bar with some small gap .
the image div should not occupy full screen , so i put it in container class